# How to call a page from another domain to my domain using ajax/javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, cross-domain, html

I would like to call and show a page from another domain to my domain using ajax/javascript. I would like to hide the original url of the page. (Example in the case of surveymoneky, I can load the survey page in my web site with out showing the surverymonkyes url.)

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance..

Regards,

Sunil

Comment: you cannot do a Cross-Origin ajax call (unless you are allowed to)

Comment: Dear Fabrizio, thanks for your time . I would like to make a demo of surveymonkey. Then how can I push my survey page to my clients with out showing my server url... please make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the SOP (same origin policy) implemented in browsers, you can only retrieve information from another domain using Ajax if the other domain allows that by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to the domain where the request originated.

Comment: Dear devnull Thanks for your valuable time and support . Could u plz make it clear please...

Comment: I am trying to push my service page to my clients web site , I would like to hide my domain url in that page . How can I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header in my visitors side. Could u plz direct me to the right way... Thanks

Comment: Example for PHP: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.yourotherdomain.com')` where www.yourotherdomain.com is the domain that sends the request